# Event is not firing after adding delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegates

I am using [jquery searchable plugin](https://github.com/stidges/jquery-searchable) to provide a searchable list. I have added another rows to existing table using below code

```
$('.add-package').unbind("click").on("click", function(){
            var packageName = $('#container-search').val();
            var newRowContent = '<tr>'+
                '<td>'+
                '<div class="row row-padding">'+
                '<div class="col-xs-4">'+packageName+'</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</td>'+
                '<td><button>delete</button></td>'+
                '</tr>';
            $("[id^=searchable-container] > table > tbody").append(newRowContent);
            $('#container-search').val(null);
            $('#container-search').keyup();
        });
```

After adding another rows they are not searchable when I type. I checked the code in [searchable.js](https://github.com/stidges/jquery-searchable/blob/master/jquery.searchable.js) and found that below code is fired when I type on search field.

```
this.$search.on( 'change keyup', function() {
                that.search( $( this ).val() );

                that.updateStriping();
            });
```

Since above code will work for existing list items(or table rows) only, I changed the code as below to add delegation

```
 this.$search.on( 'change keyup', 'tbody tr' ,function() {
                    that.search( $( this ).val() );

                    that.updateStriping();
                });
```

Anyway after added the selector for delegation this code will not fire and search will not work. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I can show a minimal version of this problem in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laki88/ur9L6e9z/). Remove `.laki` and run the example. It will fire click event. but when after adding `.laki` to add delegation, click event will not firing.

Comment: Looks like this plugin just stores the elements when the page loads. I think you will just have to reinitialise the plugin when you add new rows in.

Comment: @haxtbh: maybe. Anyway when I delegates by adding selector to the on click event(which is for adding element to list) that click event also will not work

Comment: Changing the plugin source code is never recommended unless you really need to. The change you made may causes issues else where in the plugin which may also give js errors causing other scripts to stop working

Comment: @haxtbh: but that is an issue which we need to fix.right?

Comment: @haxtbh: I added a minimal version of this problem. can you have a look what is the problem there?

Comment: Delegation doesnt work the way you have it. I have updated the fiddle to show how it works. - https://jsfiddle.net/omwg4jh8/3/

Comment: @haxtbh: Thanks. but still didn't get an idea how to fix this in plugin..:(